# Send Keyboard Input to VMWare from C#

Tags: c#, winapi, vmware, virtualbox

I want to send mouse clicks and keyboards keys to a window running a virtual machine such as VMware or VirtualBox. I want to pilotate it from the host OS, from an application written in C#.

I can move and click the mouse.

But I can't send keyboard input. I tried with SendKeys but it doesn't work. With every other "normal" window, it works. But I think it's related to how VMware or Virtual BOx intercept keyboard events.

Any idea?

Comment: consider this question ...
[send keyboard events (keystrokes) to a VirtualBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51275313/sending-mouse-or-touch-events-to-virtualbox-vm-from-host-shell)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, SendKeys and VMWare (like mstsc) don't love one each other.
But I believe that VMWare has some API functions for do so. Try to search here: 
http://www.vmware.com/support/pubs/sdk_pubs.html

Comment: vmware apis don't support keyboard input :(