# Sending mouse or touch events to VirtualBox VM from host shell?

Tags: click, virtual-machine, mouseevent, virtualbox, simulate

I know how to send keyboard events (keystrokes) to a VirtualBox Virtual Machine, using `VBoxManage controlvm keyboardputscancode <scancode> <scancode> <etc...>`

Is there a similar way to simulate **mouse or touch events**? For example, move the mouse to a certain coordinate or over a certain distance, or send a mouse click, or send a touch/tap on a given coordinate?

Comment: Identical question asked on [VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=88675).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Python and https://pypi.org/project/vboxapi/

```py
from vboxapi import VirtualBoxManager

mgr = VirtualBoxManager(None, None)
vbox = mgr.getVirtualBox()
machine = vbox.findMachine('CentOS')
session = mgr.getSessionObject(vbox)
machine.LockMachine(session, mgr.constants.LockType_Shared)
session.Console.Mouse.putMouseEventAbsolute(100,100,0,0,1)
```

for more information, please see it [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/sdkref/interface_i_mouse.html)

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising! However if I run this example (after renaming 'CentOS' to my VM name of course) I get an error: AttributeError: XPCOM component '<unknown>' has no attribute 'LockMachine' ([full error message](https://pastebin.com/raw/faiFmhUZ))

Comment: you should install vboxapi using the command *python pip install vboxapi*