# Detect Changes in Virtualbox Guest & Click on it, using Python

Tags: python, android, virtualbox, object-detection

If we have a Virtualbox guest running Android, is it possible for Python (maybe via `vboxapi` or a similar library) to

1. Detect when a button containing a certain text appears
2. Then click on this button?

The clicking at a particular screen coordinates [can be done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55643925/3023615) using `.Console.Mouse.putMouseEventAbsolute(100,100,0,0,1)`, but how can we detect changes to the Virtualbox guest display?

Answer (score 1):

You can take screenshots from time to time using `takeScreenShot()` or `takeScreenShotToArray()` and  check in the screenshot for some specific text using pytesseract, for example, or you can check for a pixel color change if you know the position where a button will appear. Then you can get the position where this changes occur and move the pointer and click based on this changes.